# JS - JSON Parsing one has many

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I couldn't find any similar question, so excuse me if this is similar to another. I have a JSON that has this structure:

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "autores": { "autor": "Sérgio Pacheco Neves" }
    },
    {
      "autores": {
        "autor": [
          "Julia Barbosa Curto",
          "Roberta Mary Vidotti",
          "Richard J. Blakely",
          "Reinhardt Adolfo"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to take each "autor" as an individial record and push it into a array. As you can see sometimes it had 1 and sometimes an array with n values. This must be achieved using javascript (jquery). I tried this:

```
var autores = [];
$.each(contentData, function(i, v) {
    $.each(this.autores, function(j, w) {
        autores.push(w);
    });
});
console.log(autores);
```

But instead of iterating over every autor in autores i get this:

```
0: "Sérgio Pacheco Neves"
1: Array[4]
  0: "Julia Barbosa Curto"
  1: "Roberta Mary Vidotti"
  2: "Richard J. Blakely"
  3: "Reinhardt Adolfo"
```

I wish to achieve something like this:

```
0: "Sérgio Pacheco Neves"
1: "Julia Barbosa Curto"
2: "Roberta Mary Vidotti"
3: "Richard J. Blakely"
4: "Reinhardt Adolfo"
```

how can i do that?

Comment: If you have any control over the piece generating the JSON, the best thing to do is fix it. `autor` should reliably be an array, even if there's only one entry in it. Having it sometimes be an array and sometimes not is poor design.

Comment: I could do that, but the problem is that i have over 2000 records.
If i do this I'll have to do three each(), correct?

Comment: No, not necessarily -- but even if you did, it's not like the computer would blink. You seem to be building a master array of all of the authors, in which case you'd just append each `autor` array to it. (Side note: I'd use the built-in `forEach` on arrays rather than jQuery's `$.each` unless you have to support IE8 or something.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with your existing structure without changing it, you can do that by checking whether the entry you're visiting is an array and, if so, pushing all of its entires on `autores`:

```
var autores = [];
$.each(contentData, function(i, v) {
    $.each(this.autores, function(j, w) {
        if (typeof w === "object") {        // That's what it says for arrays
            autores.push.apply(autores, w); // Push all of w's entries
        } else {
            autores.push(w);
        }
    });
});
console.log(autores);
```

But as I said in a comment, I would modify the structure so it **always** returns an array for `autor`, even if it only has one entry.

Answer (score 0):

Check the typeof data your receiving, add the string directly to the array and else if data is an array concatenate it to existing array.

```
 var autores = [];
    $.each(contentData, function(i, v) {
        $.each(this.autores, function(j, w) {
           if(typeof w === "string")
            autores.push(w);
            else 
            autores = autores.concat(w)
        });
    });
    console.log(autores);
```

Comment: The line `autores.concat(w)` needs to be `autores = autores.concat(w)`

Answer (score 0):

And here's a third way of distinguishing the cases, and populating your array:

```
var autores = [];
$.each(contentData, function(i, v) {
    $.each(this.autores, function(j, w) {
        if (w instanceof Array) {
          $.merge(autores, w);
        } else if (typeof w === "string") {
          autores.push(w);
        }
    });
});
console.log(autores);
```